# Display result to table using sql arithmetic query

Tags: php, sql, arithmetic-expressions

I want to display the result to table using this code

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
mysqli_select_db($con,"ofes");
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_summative_results WHERE subject_description = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$sql1="SELECT (round(AVG(pr1+pr2+pr3+pr4+pr5+pr6+pr7+pr8+pr9)/9,2)) FROM tbl_summative_results WHERE subject_description = '".$q."'";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='background-color:#e9efc4;color:black;font-weight:bold'>" . $row['(round(AVG(pr1+pr2+pr3+pr4+pr5+pr6+pr7+pr8+pr9)/9,2))'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     mysqli_close($con);
}
```

When I run the code I always have an error.

Comment: And the error is....?

Answer (score 0):

Ive got it now. I used this query "SELECT round(AVG(pr1+pr2+pr3+pr4+pr5+pr6+pr7+pr8+pr9)/9,2) FROM tbl_summative_results WHERE subject_description = '".$q."'";"

Comment: I only remove the parenthesis beside the round in the query